# Ordenar por valor fora da query MySql

Tags: php, mysql

Preciso ordenar o resultado da minha pesquisa por um valor q esta fora da query.

> Por exemplo, na consulta tenho um campo chamado resposta e com esse
>   valor faço um calculo. Mas o resultado desse calculo não esta na
>   tabela.

Minha query

```
$search = mysql_query('SELECT * FROM simuladosrespondidos AS sr 
            JOIN usuarios AS u ON u.idUsuarios = '.$idUsuario.' AND sr.idUsuarios = u.idUsuarios 
            JOIN questoes AS q ON q.idQuestao = sr.idQuestao WHERE sr.idSimulado = '.$idSimulado.'');
```

O que faço é pegar o valor de uma coluna chamada respostas e fazer o calculo em cima dele.
Como ordenar por esse calculo?

Obs: O calculo q faço na verdade é o seguinte: Pego o valor da coluna resposta. Cada usuario tem varias respostas. Se for igual a 'C' somo + 1 em uma variavel aqui. Se for igual a 'E' diminuo - 1 e se for igual a E nao faço nada e no final de tudo tenho um valor e é por esse valor q quero ordenar.

Comment: Poste como está sua query. Exemplos de valores para ficar mais facil visualizar sua necessidade.

Comment: Você esta fazendo seu calculo no mysql ou no php?

Comment: Editei com a minha query

Comment: Edite novamente com o resultado depois que você faz o calculo.

Comment: Editei a pergunta galera

Comment: Passa mais informações, se de alguma maneira você estiver guardando um array com o calculo das informações, de certo ou errado e valor final . Você pode ordenar esse array com o PHP.